# php mysqli I do not get information not available

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, group1 and group2. 
With 3 columns, 'id', 
'status' (0-Available, 1-Not available) and
'description' for the number 0 and 1 (Available and Not available)

When there is a 0 in the column it works well, and it shows the 'description' for that number,but 
when all the numbers in the column are 1 it will not output my 
else statement, dont know why? It standing still in the if statament.

I do not know how to output more rows 
when i have more zeros in the table.

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

   <form name='search' method="post">
     <select name='onoroff'>

       <option value='group1' >Group 1</option>
       <option value='group2' >Group 2</option>

       </select>
     </datalist>
  <input type='submit' name='run' value="Go"/>
  </form>

<?php

//////////////////////////////////////////////
$group = ($_POST['onoroff']);

$q= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $group WHERE status = 0");
$r= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);

if (isset($_POST['run'])) {
  echo '<p>'.$r['description'].'</p>';
    } else { echo '<p>Not available</p>';}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"but when all the numbers in the column are 1 it will not output my else statement"* - Because, that's what you asked for it to look for in your query, `0`.

Comment: When i do "SELECT * FROM $ulica_name" and another "if (r['status']==0){..." it still not working. In that case i always get the result ande the current data for the first row, no matter if is in the status 0 or 1.

Comment: The `else` statement has nothing to do with what's in the table. It's just based on whether `$_POST['run']` is set, which depends on whether the form was submitted or you're opening the page for the first time.

Comment: @DaliborGrujic What exactly do you want this query to do? Show the description if status is 0 and not available if status is 1?

Comment: To show the description if status is 0 , but if is status 1 just simple echo Not available.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the database query inside the `if(isset($_POST['run']))` block. Otherwise, you're trying to use `$_POST['onoroff']` even though the user hasn't submitted the form yet.

```
if (isset($_POST['run'])) {
    $group = ($_POST['onoroff']);
    $q= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $group WHERE status = 0");
    $r= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
    echo '<p>'.$r['description'].'</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Not available</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the if statements with the returned value of the status will choose what is displayed depending on their status.

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>

       <form name='search' method="post">
         <select name='onoroff'>

           <option value='group1' >Group 1</option>
           <option value='group2' >Group 2</option>

           </select>
         </datalist>
      <input type='submit' name='run' value="Go"/>
      </form>

    <?php

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    $group = ($_POST['onoroff']);
    if (isset($_POST['run'])) 
    {
        $q= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $group");
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            if($r['status'] == 0) {
                echo '<p>'.$r['id'].' : '.$r['description'].'</p>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<p>'.$r['id'].' Not available</p>';
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo '<p>You need to submit to choose a group</p>';
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
     ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I did exactly like that. But now im getting only the else statements. And i have a 0 in the table group1

Comment: Try changing it to include a while loop. Perhaps only the last line is being printed out? See my edited answer